# Unable to hide/show nav bar within index.html using ng-hide directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing my first small web app, that is a CMS.

Anyway, once the user logs in, I want to be able to hide or show the nav bar in index.html by manipulating the ng-hide directive.

Here is my code so far.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="WebAppApp">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-hide="menuHide">
        <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div ng-view=""></div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/login.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/signup.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/home.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/apiService.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/loggedinService.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

I have defined the ng-hide directive in the nav tag within index.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-hide="menuShowHide">
```

Controller

home.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, loggedInStatus, apiServiceWeb) {

//unhide menu by accessing ng-hide variable set in index.html
  $scope.menuHide = false;

});
```

Within a controller I now want to be able to set true or false for the navigation that way through:

`$scope.menuHide = false;` or

```
$scope.menuHide = true;
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea why this is happening and how I can make this work?

Thanks

Comment: can you create a plunkr or fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Create a jsFiddle example.

1. Do you call a `homeCtrl`?For example like this 
   `<div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-hide="menuHide">
   </div>`
2. Create a breakpoint in your controller and check is it creating or not.

Comment: I call the homeCtrl through app.js routes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to set `menuShowHide`, which isn't scoped to the `homeCtrl` from within `homeCtrl`. The best way to fix this is by either creating a new controller to handle the menu show hide, but if you're trying to set the visibility from other controllers you will need to use AngularJS [Services/Factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

A quick and dirty workaround would be to set `menuShowHide` using `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $rootScope, $location, loggedInStatus, apiServiceWeb) {

  //unhide menu by accessing ng-hide variable set in index.html
  $rootScope.menuShowHide = false;

});
```

Comment: After the controller has loaded is there a way I can check the state from a cookie, i.e. if they have logged in or logged out?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible, as long as you set the cookie when the user logs in and delete it when he logs out, you should be able to read it from any controller.